# Invalid Return Type in pyspark for UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a strange issue in pyspark where I want to define and use a UDF. I am always getting this error:

> TypeError: Invalid returnType: returnType should be DataType or str but is <'pyspark.sql.types.IntegerType'>

My code is actually very simple:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def square(x):
    return 2

def _process():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('process').getOrCreate()
    spark_udf = udf(square,IntegerType)
```

The problem is probably with the IntegerType but I don't know what is wrong with that. I am using `Python version 3.5.3` and the `spark version 2.4.1`

Comment: you are missing parentheses after `IntegerType`. the correct declaration would be `spark_udf = udf(square,IntegerType())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `IntegerType` directly without calling it is causing issue

```
def _process():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName('process').getOrCreate()
    spark_udf = udf(square,IntegerType())
```

Try by calling the type `IntegerType()` and it should work fine.